# Cache Model array with attr_accessor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, attr-accessor

When I add a attr_accessor to my model without the column in the database, I can add temporary data to an array of class objects.

My example :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :score
end
```

The problem however is that if cache in memcache an array of users with scores, the array goes from :

```
[< User >, < User >, < User >]
```

to:

```
[< User >, :@score, 100, < User >, :@score, 200, < User >, :@score, 300]
```

Is there any way to cache this information without breaking the array ?

EDIT : As requested, the actual code that puts the data in the cache :

```
  def users_scoreboard
    Rails.cache.fetch("special_scoreboard_#{self.cache_key}", :expires_in => 1.hour) do
      users = Photo.missions(self.missions).created(self.start_at, self.end_at).map(&:user).uniq!
      users = [] if users.nil?
      users.each do |u|
        u.score = u.score_for_special(self)
      end
      users.sort! { |a,b| b.score <=> a.score }
    end
  end
```

EDIT : What I'm using :

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.1]

rails -v
Rails 3.2.0

memcached -i
memcached 1.4.5

memcached -i
memcached 1.4.5

gem -v dalli
1.8.8
```

But the problem appears either with Memcache or with the filestore.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Show us the code that puts the array into memcache.

Comment: I've just updated the question :)

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I'm on rails 3.2, memcache-client 1.8.5, memcached 1.4.7 and `users_scoreboard` always returns an array of `Users` for me.

Comment: Yea even with Rails 3.0 and Dalli with memcached 1.4.4 it seems to be working fine. Is there some piece of code you aren't including?

Comment: Well there certainly must be, but it is out of the scope of these lines, so it might either be a weird gem, of some of the stuff in my User model definition. I endend up using simple hashes with ids and score for now.

Comment: Please tell us the versions your are using, ruby, rails, memcached and memcache-client or dalli

Comment: Done, the question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cattr_accessor, it'll add the accessor method onto the class as well. This worked for me.